# How to show an error outside of a form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I wanted to show an error message in a view/method that I created. The thing is that I add the error in the model as you can see in the following code:

```
errors.add :base, 'It can't be destroyed because some users use it'
```

But in the view when I try to render, the error is not shown.

I copied the error rendering mechanism of a form.
Do I have to make a form or something like that to show the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure two things:

1. you have the following block in the view template:

   ```
   <%= @posts.errors.full_message.each |key, value| %> 
     # display value
   <% end %>
   ```
2. assign an error message in your controller:

   ```
   redirect_to posts_path, flash[:alert] = "It can't be destroyed because some users use it"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you could just use the [flash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html) functionality for errors. When your controller receives the error from your model do something like:

```
redirect_to show_url(@post), alert: "It can't be destroyed because some users use it"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add an error message anywhere in your view template when a validation error occurs. It would look something like this:

```
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are updating single dogs within the dogs `index` view, the solution when you need to show validation errors quickly without Javascript and outside of the form, is to send an array of errors like a single error to errors partial in layout and iterate there through them.

Note that this method is not conventional and has some drawbacks. You need to `redirect_to` from the controller, because `render` [won't work well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621928/rails-refreshing-page-after-calling-render-on-failed-validation), so you will have the page refreshed and bubbled up (propagated) to the top.

```rb
# dogs_controller.rb
class DogsController
  def index
    @dogs = Dog.all
  end

  def update
    if dog.update
      # ...
    else
      flash[:danger] = dog.errors.full_messages
      redirect_to dogs_path
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/views/layouts/_errors.html.haml
- flash.each do |message_type, message|
  - if message.is_a?(Array)
    # show validation errors outside of form workaround
    - message.each do |msg|
      .alert.alert-danger= msg
  - else
    # usual error handler (from controller flash)
    = content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}")
```