# Rails refreshing page after calling render on failed validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a controller action looking like this:

```
def create
  @term = Term.new(term_params)
  if @term.save
    redirect_to(@term)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

When validation fails the new actions view is rendered and user can see the errors that were made. The problem is that this also changes the URL to `localhost:3000/terms` so when the user would for some reason want to refresh the page, then rails would want to redirect that user to terms `index` page. Is there a simple way to keep the user on the `new term` page after refresh?

I actually don't have a `index` page for `terms` as I dont't need it, so this whole situation will throw an error in this case.

Comment: If you don't want to change the url on validation fail. Handle create action through ajax. As If you will `render` it will show create url only.

Answer (score 3):

Please,take this in consideration:

Your are seeing `terms` but is not the same like the "index of terms". Thing is, using https, in the path of your "new" action. Index use "get" and create use "post". So, looks the same but is not.

I think in your routes files, you need to define the "post" path in a explict way.

```
post "new-term" => terms#new
```

and maybe define in your controller to:

```
render new_term_path
```

Comment: Feels a bit hackish :/

Comment: In short terms:

Index action, use Https "get" method. This method will get all data. Create action use Https "post" method. Is important you notice the difference. You may see the same in the url, but is not.

Then, you just need to implement the method that I mentioned above. I think you can do even something like: "redirect_to new_term_path" and don't pass the @term object because is not created.

I think is you use this: redirect_to new_term_path you won't see the error message again when refresh the page, becase the call is now redircting the full_path and not just the template

Answer (score 2):

It's important to realize that when you do `render :new` inside your `create` action, you're not actually routing to and running the `new` action, you're simply rendering the *new* template (i.e. `new.html.erb`) so the URL reflects the URL of the create action (in your case `/terms`).

If you wanted to actually route your users to `/terms/new`, you can `redirect_to new_term_path` if the save fails although that would also prevent your users from seeing the validation errors.

Since you mentioned that you are not actually using the `index` action to render anything meaningful, have it perform the redirect

```
def index
  redirect_to new_term_path
end
```

This way if the user happens to refresh the page, they'll be redirected back to the new form. This isn't a general solution but should work well in your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a fix. Make the `resources` in your route.rb file as `resource`. This will not create the index action unless you explicity ask for it like:

```
resources :posts, :only => [:index, :create, :show]
```

otherwise it will not generate the index action if you do this in `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :posts
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I do need the id tough. This would lose the params.

Comment: No it will not. The redirection will have the params placed in the fields

Comment: Now it will want to render the show actions view. That's not much better also :D

Comment: thats strange. Which url it renders ?

Comment: /term. And according to documentation this will lead to show.